# doc not coming back in my results though it's requested in the options

Tags: pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB 3.0.5 with a query call that requests documents (via the include_docs: true option) but the doc property isn't there (id, key, and value are).  What am I doing wrong?

Here's the view:

```
  {
     "_id": "_design/clubbers",
     "language": "javascript",
     "views": {
         "clubbers": {
             "map": "function(doc) {\n  if (doc.type === 'clubber') {\n    emit([doc.firstName, doc.lastName], doc.club);\n  }\n}"
         }
     }
  }
```

And here is the call and what I'm getting back:

[image]

UPDATED:

When I step through the unminified pouchdb.js, it seems to skip from line 9375 (where it sets the "var promise = Promise.resolve..." to the "utils.promisedCallback..." line and never goes into the "then" of the aforementioned line.  I even placed a line in there to catch an error and write it to the console, and it was skipped also. The opts looked correct the whole way through.

```
exports.query = function (fun, opts, callback) {
  if (typeof opts === 'function') {
    callback = opts;
    opts = {};
  }
  opts = utils.extend(true, {}, opts);

  if (typeof fun === 'function') {
    fun = {map : fun};
  }

  var db = this;
  var promise = Promise.resolve().then(function () {
    return queryPromised(db, fun, opts);
  });
  utils.promisedCallback(promise, callback);
  return promise;
};
```

CORRECTION:

It did get to that section of code that nlawson pointed out, but it skipped over the line that says "row.doc = joinedDoc"

Answer (score 0):

That's really weird. Looking at your code, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be returning the docs.

Could you use the unminified version of PouchDB, step through the code, and make sure that [this line](https://github.com/pouchdb/mapreduce/blob/master/index.js#L537-L550) is being hit?

Comment: line 542 is never being hit (see updated question), but it does try to process the line before that.

Comment: It looks like most of the documents that came back from the query are deleted (why are they coming back then?) and there is one that is not deleted and it does have the doc property -- but the deleted ones do not.  So I guess my question is now why are deleted records coming back in my query and how do I know which ones are deleted (nothing in the result set tells me that)?

Comment: It sounds like you may have found a bug. I've filed it here: https://github.com/pouchdb/mapreduce/issues/213. If you could provide some more details in that GitHub issue, that would be really helpful. E.g. when did you delete documents, when did you last query the view, etc. Thanks! :)

Comment: Also there is technically a race condition in include_docs in queries (exists in CouchDB too), so if you're deleting documents at the same time that you're querying, this might occur. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: I had deleted the documents, and then ran the query.  I would then keep retrying the query (via a refresh button) to trace down the problem.

Comment: Let's move discussion to the GitHub issue, because I think you've identified a real problem. Could you provide more details there please?